# Bulk move from sp online to onedrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, move, onedrive, bulk

So I have a need to migrate thousands of user files from sharepoint obkine to onedrive. Basically the company migrated their drive shares to sharepoint including user accounts. Now they want to move those user accounts to onedrive. I have tried using spmt and it seems to not recognize my destination address. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.